# Queue Anylogic Prio-based

Tags: anylogic

I have a production. In the queues in front of the respective machine, I would like to prioritize the orders that have the shortest processing time. The information is read from a table.
What is the best way to implement this?
So far I have tried to prioritize the agent with the smallest number. But it did not work.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add a `double` field in your agent type `processingDur`
2. fill it as required from your data
3. in the `Queue`, make sure you actually send through your custom agent type
4. in the `Queue` "agent priority" field, type `agent.processingDur`

Now, your agents will be sorted in the queue by the duration

Comment: oke thanks, but how do I know that they are sorted according to the shortest or longest duration?

Comment: Its in the documentation and sorted "naturally", i.e. from small to large. HOWEVER: Always test these things manually :) Also, pls upvote if a reply was useful, helps future users to find it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote